# Get prefill input value ionic angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I retrieve some data on init from an API and display them in my view to prefill some fields.

I'm a form view which contains :

```
<ion-textarea formControlName="job_description" class="form-control desc" value="{{resDesc?.job_description}}"></ion-textarea>
```

And when I submit the form, I try to get datas with :

```
this.form.get('job_description').value
```

And it's always null... Except if I write something in the field.

What should I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the value in the  tag you can set it in your TS file, like this:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  job_description: new FormControl("YOUR VALUE HERE")
});
```

It works in my computer ...

Comment: Thanks ! It helps me to find a solution, I did it with `this.form.controls[“job_description”].setValue(this.job_description);` after calling API.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `patchValue` or `setValue` to set the default values of all the fields in your model. See Angular docs on [patchValue and setValue](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#partial-model-updates). I like `patchValue` for this use case.

**setValue():**

> Use the `setValue()` method to set a new value for an individual control. The `setValue()` method strictly adheres to the structure of the form group and replaces the entire value for the control.

**patchValue():**

> Use the `patchValue()` method to replace any properties defined in the object that have changed in the form model.

**Example**:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('/my-api).subscribe(data => {
        this.form.patchValue(data)
    });
}
```